# Parse file and insert new line after each occurrence

Tags: perl, sed, ksh, aix

On a Unix system I am trying to add a new line in a file using `sed` or `perl` but it seems I am missing something.

Supposing my file has multiple lines of texts, always ending like this `{TNG:}}${1:F01`.

I am trying to find a to way to add a new line after the `}$`, in this way `{1` should always start on a new line.

I tried it by escaping `$` sign using this:

`perl -e '$/ = "\${"; while (<>) { s/\$}\{$/}\n{/; print; }'` but it does not work.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With perl:

```
$ cat input.txt
line 1 {TNG:}}${1:F01
line 2 {TNG:}}${1:F01
$ perl -pe 's/TNG:\}\}\$\K/\n/' input.txt 
line 1 {TNG:}}$
{1:F01
line 2 {TNG:}}$
{1:F01
```

(Read up on the `-p` and `-n` options in [perlrun](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun) and use them instead of trying to do what they do in a one-liner yourself)

Comment: @Mihaimyh Nice. I wasn't entirely sure if you'd have a perl new enough to use that `\K` construct. It was added a long time ago (perl 5.10), but commercial unixes don't exactly have a reputation for staying up to date...

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
sed 's/{TNG:}}\$/&\n/' file > newfile
```

The sed will by default use BRE, that is, the `{}`s are literal characters. But we must escape the `$`.

```
kent$  cat f
{TNG:}}${1:F01.

kent$  sed 's/{TNG:}}\$/&\n/' f
{TNG:}}$
{1:F01.
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just adds `n` in the string and not a new line. `-}{5:{TNG:}}$n{1:`

Comment: @Mihaimyh which sed do you use? It works here with gnu sed.

Comment: I am using sed on AIX 7.2

Comment: @Mihaimyh it doesn't tell which sed do you use. pls report  the sed version. Also check the man page of your sed, you may need some option like `-E`.

Comment: Indeed this works with gnu sed, but on AIX it does not. I will try to provide with `sed` version but I cannot find it.

Comment: Correction: instead of `\n` use \\_actualnewline_